# Can't get pip3.10 to work directly in Ubuntu

Tags: pip

I'm getting this:

```
$ pip3.10
pip3.10: command not found
```

Now, I have python3.10 installed correctly:

```
$ python3.10 --version
Python 3.10.10
```

And I have installed pip within it:

```
$ python3.10 -m pip

 Usage:   
    /usr/bin/python3.10 -m pip <command> [options]
 ....
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think pip3.10 is not installed or not in your system path, you dont need a separate pip3.10 command
Simply use the following: `python3.10 -m pip <command> [options]`

For example if you wanted to install a package `python3.10 -m pip install <package>`

Comment: I know, but I have a script (that not I control) that uses pip3.10 so I need to figure out how to make that command work...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for your use-case you just want to be able to enter the command

```
$ pip3.10 <args>
```

and have it give the same output as

```
$ python3.10 -m pip <args>
```

So I'd think the simplest way is to either make an alias and add it to your `~/.bashrc` file. You could just add this at the end of the file:

```
alias pip3.10="python3.10 -m pip"
```

Any new shells logging in as your user will now be able to enter `pip3.10` and have it be interpreted as `python3.10 -m pip`